# Поиск в TreeView

Tags: c#

Прохожусь по столбцу в dataGridView и если есть значение, которого нет в TreeView, то оно должно добавляется. На деле существующие значения дублируются. Подскажите в чём ошибка.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
         if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() != treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[j].Name.ToString()) ;
        {
treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
         }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  bool found = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count; j++)
  {
    if (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes[j].Name.ToString()) ;
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) 
  {
    treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
  }
}
```